# What are the potential effects of mobile phones on pacemaker function?

Tags: cardiology, effectiveness, risks, cellular-phone

I was wondering if mobile phone can negatively effect pacemakers.

Most websites recommend reduced phone usage, but I can't find any research that explains how they can interfere with pacemakers. 
Can you point me to any serious references about this subject ?

Comment: Have a look at some of these posts for a general information but we do not answer personal medical questions: [1](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/30524/3340), [2](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/39422/3340). These posts are not really about pacemaker function though, but may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Phones can interfere with pacemakers, but usually the [effects are rare](http://www.healthline.com/health-news/smartphones-can-occasionally-interfere-with-pacemakers-062315) and can be avoided.

> Dr. Carsten Lennerz, study lead author and cardiology resident in the
>   Clinic for Heart and Circulatory Diseases at Munich’s German Heart
>   Centre, said that pacemakers in rare instances can mistakenly detect
>   electromagnetic interference from mobile phones. The devices can then
>   interpret the interference as a cardiac signal, causing them to
>   briefly stop working. This can sometimes result in the patient
>   fainting.

- [fda.gov](http://www.fda.gov/Radiation-EmittingProducts/RadiationEmittingProductsandProcedures/HomeBusinessandEntertainment/CellPhones/ucm116311.htm)

> Radiofrequency energy (RF) from cell phones can interact with some
>   electronic devices. This type of interference is called
>   electromagnetic interference (EMI). For this reason, FDA helped
>   develop a detailed test method to measure EMI of implanted cardiac
>   pacemakers and defibrillators from cell phones. This test method is
>   now part of a standard sponsored by the Association for the
>   Advancement of Medical Instrumentation (AAMI). This standard will
>   allow manufacturers to ensure that cardiac pacemakers and
>   defibrillators are safe from cell phone EMI.

If EMI were to occur it could cauae:

> Stopping the pacemaker from delivering the stimulating pulses that
>   regulate the heart's rhythm Causing the pacemaker to deliver the
>   pulses irregularly Causing the pacemaker to ignore the heart's own
>   rhythm and deliver pulses at a fixed rate

However,

> But based on current research, cell phones would not seem to pose a
>   significant health problem for the vast majority of pacemaker wearers.
>   Still, people with pacemakers may want to take some simple precautions
>   to be sure that their cell phones don't cause a problem.

- [The effects of mobile phones on pacemaker function](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16061124): study

This study just says that phones effect pacemakers, but once you take the phone away the pacemaker is fine once again.

- [heart.gov](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Conditions/Arrhythmia/PreventionTreatmentofArrhythmia/Devices-that-may-Interfere-with-Pacemakers_UCM_302013_Article.jsp#mainContent)

Phones available in the US(less than 3 watts) don't appear to affect pacemaker function. However, new phones using new frequencies may make pacemakers unreliable.

- [MedicineNet.com](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/mobileart.asp?articlekey=616): mentions a study

> Of important note, the pacemaker interference by the cellular phones
>   was only found to be significant when the phones were held over the
>   pacemakers-not when placed in the normal listening position over the
>   ear.

- [Healthline.com](http://www.healthline.com/health-news/smartphones-can-occasionally-interfere-with-pacemakers-062315)
- [Third-Generation Mobile Phones (UMTS) do not Interfere with Permanent Implanted Pacemakers](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/726466)

Comment: Also telling is the large number of hospitals that once banned cell phone usage and now don't bother.